# detox build fails on mac, nvm not compatible with the "PREFIX" environment variable

Tags: macos, react-native, build, nvm, detox

When using nvm to manage node versions on MacOS(11.1), detox build fails with the following error

```
nvm is not compatible with the "PREFIX" environment variable: currently set to "/Users/uloco/.nvm/versions/node/v15.6.0"
Run `unset PREFIX` to unset it.
env: node: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Ubuntu works fine with nvm.
Also other builds that need node or npm work fine, it is just happening with detox.

Is detox setting the PREFIX environment variable somewhere?
s there any way of working around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was still an issue by npm 2 days ago.
It used to set the $PREFIX env variable for no reason.

Now it is fixed, see: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2398

`nvm install-lastest-npm` fixes this, no need to unset prefix anymore.
(For me this was version 7.5.2)